# Datadog Template Variable String Interpolation

Tags: monitoring, datadog

I'm trying to build a dashboard that shows cpu and cpu throttling on a per kube deployment basis. So for cpu it's easy. I have my deployment template variable and I just use it as is. `kube_deployment:$deployment.value` but CPU throttling is captured at the pod level, and what I would like to be able to do is something like this: `pod_name:${deployment.value}-*` and append a literal "-*" to the end of the deployment name to get all the pods from that deployment. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated this myself as I needed the same thing, long story short, it turns out that wildcards are not supported for Metrics yet.

#### Source:

I reached out to Datadog support, and they confirmed this.
They also redirected me to [THIS](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/#logs-apm-and-rum-queries) documentation page that does not say that directly. It only says that it is supported for Logs, APM, and RUM queries.
Hope this helps.